# Getting 500 Internal server error with open uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bookmarking site, done in ruby on rails, in which lots of URLs needed to be open and crawl its title and base_uri. Th method used for opening URL is open(url). When I tried to open http://www.mysite.com/ with open URI method, I got 500 Internal server error.

OpenURI::HTTPError in TestsController#test

500 Internal Server Error

I can access this URL through browser.

My code posted below

```
require 'hpricot'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'timeout'
    require 'net/http'
url = 'http://www.mysite.com/'
@filep   = open(url)
base_uri =    @filep.base_uri
```

I tried the same with hpricot too using the code.

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read) but getting the same error.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Work for me. Are you sure you haven't mapped mysite.com in your /etc/hosts to an internal site?

Comment: No I have not mapped. Its an external site which I need to crawl.

Comment: Do you get the same issue using irb?

Comment: does your website maybe block requests that come over non-ssl traffic? your URL sets `http` as a protocol. Try `https`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem; could open the website in my browser but not through open-uri . Adding a user agent did not fix it, but using the 'restclient' class did

```
require 'restclient'
url = 'http://www....'
user_info = RestClient.get(url, "User-Agent" => "Ruby")
```